# jpanel overlap other components

Tags: java, swing, awt, oracleforms

I have serious problem when I add `JPanel` to Oracle Forms Container (based-on AWT `Container`).
I add `JPanel` first, after that I add some `VTextFields` (Oracle Forms text field).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import oracle.ewt.scrolling.scrollBox.ScrollBox;
import oracle.forms.ui.DrawnPanel;
import oracle.forms.ui.FScrollBox;
import oracle.forms.ui.VTextField;

public class OverlapTest {

int w = 800;
int h= 700;

public OverlapTest() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(w, h);

    DrawnPanel main = new DrawnPanel();

    main.setLayout(null);
    main.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
    main.setVisible(true);

    VTextField t1 = new VTextField();
    t1.setBounds(100, 100, 130, 22);

    VTextField t2 = new VTextField();
    t2.setBounds(100, 150, 130, 22);

    VTextField t3 = new VTextField();
    t3.setBounds(100, 200, 130, 22);

    final JPanel draw = new JPanel(){
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setColor(Color.red);
            g2.fillRect(0, 100, 130, 200);
            g2.dispose();

        }

        @Override
        public void update(Graphics g) {
            paint(g);
        }

    };
    draw.setOpaque(false);
    draw.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);

    main.add(draw);
    main.add(t1);
    main.add(t2);
    main.add(t3);

    ScrollBox sBox = new ScrollBox(main);
    sBox.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
    sBox.setVScrollInsets(1, 100);
    oracle.forms.ui.FScrollBox fBox = new FScrollBox(sBox, 0, 0);
    fBox.setVisible(true);
    fBox.setBounds(0, 0, w - 50, h - 50);

    main.setComponentZOrder(draw, 3);
    main.setComponentZOrder(t1, 0);
    main.setComponentZOrder(t2, 1);
    main.setComponentZOrder(t3, 2);

    f.add(fBox);

    f.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    OverlapTest test = new OverlapTest();
    }
 }
```

As you see, I add the `JPanel` first, after that I `setComponentZorde`r, that is because my requirement and in my real application I cannot add `JPanel` at the end of all component, so I did it follow that way.

But currently I have one problem, all other component overlap the `JPanel` but the background of `JPanel` (the red rectangle) always hide other components like that.

This is the image:

[image: Overlap GUI]

I don't know, but when I use `JTextField`, everything is OK.
I'm using components of Oracle Forms in `frmall.jar`
You can download `frmall.jar` from http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/329640/frmall-jar.html
Do you have any solution to make the red rectangle is overlapped by other components?

Sorry for my terible English.

Thanks in Advance.

---

now I try to replace Jpanel by Forms DrawnPanel, but it still have the problem:

```
FormCanvas form = new FormCanvas(){
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g, Dimension paramDimension,
                Rectangle paramRectangle) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.paint(g, paramDimension, paramRectangle);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setColor(Color.red);
            g2.fillRect(0, 100, 200, 200);
            g2.dispose();
        }
    };
DrawnPanel draw = new DrawnPanel();
draw.setPainter(form);
draw.setVisible(true);
```

So now, every my components are Forms Component, but I still get this problem

Comment: Wow, a 500Kb+ bitmap that reduces to an 8Kb PNG!  No wonder people don't use the bitmap format.  I've edited the small PNG directly into the thread.  For tips on creating great screen shots, see [How do I create a screenshot to illustrate a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post)

Comment: Also, consider using a less garish hosting site, perhaps one that doesn't include adult-oriented advertising.

Answer (score 3):

The first advice I would offer is **don't mix Swing & AWT components.**  Try updating the 'Oracle forms' jar to a Swing version, or failing that, use only AWT components in your code.

Comment: Hi, I know the reasion make the problem, because Jpanel is lightweight Component and AWT is heavyweight so my Jpanel always overlap another components. I searched, and I've already used com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setComponentMixingCutoutShape but it still can NOT be solved. http://today.java.net/article/2009/11/02/transparent-panel-mixing-heavyweight-and-lightweight-components . Please help me to solve it, it make me crazy

Comment: How can I know you tried my advice?  How can I help you if you ignore my advice?